# Disambiguate [pcl]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

In StackOverflow, there's the tag [pcl](/questions/tagged/pcl). Now, this could either mean Portable Class Language or Printer Control Language. However, at least 6 people (me and 5 people I've just untagged) have confused this for Portable Class Library. Considering that there's only 107 questions tagged it, that's actually quite significant.

I suggest we move [pcl](/questions/tagged/pcl) to [printer-control-language](/questions/tagged/printer-control-language) to prevent any other mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

It can also mean **Point Cloud Library**! Which is most likely meant in e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607109/object-recognition-with-kinect) question.

Comment: We can only synonymize PCL to one tag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Of course, and there already is a point-cloud-library tag. I renamed a few of the questions. I might have missed a few though.